# Link a Windows .exe with other Fortran routines on Linux

Tags: compilation, fortran

I have a Fortran ".exe" file generated in Windows. I want to link it with other Fortran routines while compiling on Linux platform.

For example, I have "a.exe" file generated on Windows. I wrote "b.f90" and "c.f90" on linux machine. I want to compile "b.f90" and "c.f90" and link them to "a.exe" to generate the final ".exe" file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

(Or it would be very very complicated and the .exe would have to be specially prepared for that.)

Not only Linux and Windows executables are incompatible. You do not link an .exe with anything, not on Windows, not on Linux, nowhere (except linking with the .dll or .so dynamic libraries the executable always requires). What you normally do is that you compile your Fortran or other language sources to object files and then you can link the object files to form a library (dynamic or static) or to form an executable.

What you could theoretically do, IF the .exe file already requires some .dll libraries, or is able to load some on request, is to compile your .f90 files to make these .dll libraries (somewhere with Windows or with a Windows compiler under Linux in Wine or with a cross-compiler) and then run everything under Linux using Wine. But I would just recompile everything on Linux from scratch.